# MapWindow - Load basemap image given extent?

Tags: wms, mapwindow

I'm new to MapWindow and am attempting to display an image given the geographic extents of an area. Tiling would be ideal, but I imagine that retrieving a simple image from a WMS would be easiest. Are there any simple examples available for this? I'm using MapWinGIS and .NET.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/462146/Georeferencing-Open-Street-Map-Tiles-to-Use-with-M

It's an article I put together to show how to Georeference Open Street Map tiles and use as a backdrop with MapWinGIS.

Ben